# How to migrate site collection using powershell (SharePoint Online)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, lookup-column, migration

The requirement is to migrate all the Lists(SharePoint Online to SharePoint Online). I have tried many ways. But Lookups don't work. It creates the lookup column with an empty reference to the other list.

I have tried this [Github](https://github.com/farchide/MSSCM)

I think the issue is the list doesn't exist when these columns are getting created.

Also tried the [site template solution](https://veronicageek.com/office-365/sharepoint-online/save-site-as-a-template-and-use-it-to-create-a-site-collection-in-sharepoint-online/2018/04/). Always gets timed out.

[image]

If anyone has successfully migrate using powershell please share.

It would be great if I can migrate the data too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A search on migration in here will show that the options are: migrate some content  using handfitted powershell or migrate the lot using either ShareGate or Metalogix.
I know that $4000 might sound expensive but so is our time so if you need to migrate and rearrange content the business case might be good

Comment: I couldn't agree more. Sharegate is the best one so far since you can migrate whatever way you want, plus it's the most affordable tool out there.